# Accessing data from a complex object that is returned by an observable

Tags: node.js, angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have an Angular client that fetches data from an observable (through apollo.watchQuery()).

When I log the data returned from the observable, the structure of it happens to be like this:
[console.log() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36l3f.png)

**How do I access each one of those 'user' objects from the main 'users' object?**

This is how I fetched and logged the data initially:  [fetching_users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV86G.png)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but i don't really understand your question here: Why don't you just iterate over your users array ? something like res.data.users.map(user => {//any treatment here}) ? or just a stupid for (const user of res.data.users) {//any treatment here} ?

Comment: Thanks @millenion, but when I try to access res.data.users, it says: "error TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type '{}'.". Easy job otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each user object with angular function forEach, in your case it's will be something like this

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>(...).valueChanges.subscribe(
  res=>{ //res here is Users
    res.forEach(
    user=>{
    console.log(user.name);
  }
})
```

Comment: I think that surely should work @kenny-samuel, but it throws an error: "error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'ApolloQueryResult<{}>'". What does that mean? Am I iterating through something undefined?

Comment: **SOLVED!** the Apollo method should be called as `apollo.watchQuery<any>(..);` and not as just `apollo.watchQuery(..);`

Comment: Nice, I will update my answer too for future reference

Comment: Extremely **useful resource** if you have the same question: [Apollo Docs] (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries/)